# Find Price/Value in PHP string

Tags: php, string, replace

I'm trying to use PHP to find a value in a string and replace it with another value, the value may be (for example) £x on one line and £x.xx on the next, but will always be replaced by a value of £x.xx. Hope that makes sense? TIA.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are not here to write code for people too lazy to even try.

Comment: Who is TIA? I thought this was Greg?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I guess TIA = **T**hanks **I**n **A**dvance, don't panic :D

Comment: That's the first time I've noticed seeing it shortened like that. If it catches on, maybe I'll also start seeing more WHYTSFs to go along with the TIAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex to match the prices: `£[0-9]+\.?[0-9]{0,2}`

You can perform the replace with this by using this function:

```
preg_replace("/£[0-9]+\.?[0-9]{0,2}/", " ** REPLACEMENT ** ", $input_lines);
```

The nice thing about `preg_replace` is that if you feed it a single line you'll get a single value back, but if you feed it an array of strings with the values you want changed it will return an array with those values replaces. Nice and tidy if you need to make a lot of replacements.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried (despite other comments) lots of combinations of the above but failed... My brain was getting tired and confused. This works a treat though.

Comment: @GregMoseley No problem, easy to get caught up in problems like this.